# How to add a custom calendar for project using Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject

Tags: c#, ms-project

I know how to add the calendar in MS project 2010 as follow picture,but I don't know how to add and read a **custom calendar** in the project file(filename.mpp) using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject`.

As I have googled the problem,but I found nothing .(just some things about adding the task and so on on the other hand there are no help files on `MSDN` for `Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject`)

I found third part dll(aspose task for .net) to read the calendars [Retrieving+Calendar+Information](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/tasksnet/Retrieving+Calendar+Information),but the interop.MSPorject is different from it.

[image: In MS project 2010 add the custom calendar][image: try to find the custom calendars]

Comment: The problem in this question is that you don't know something (as you have said), the solution for your problem is to learn that thing (maybe books, google, etc).

Comment: @Transcendent I have googled it, but there are no help files from MSDN

Comment: Regarding adding the calendar, I don't know much about project, but assuming you can create a calendar and save that (in case you wanna reuse it), you can create a template file and load it in there. This post may help you on reading it http://www.nerdyhearn.com/blog/156/

Comment: @I have try to read the  properties  of Project,but I can't find which properties is the custom calendar.

Comment: Did you try `if (calendar.Name.Eqauls("Something"))` to find the custom calender ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to keep in mind when developing code for MS Project:

1. Many methods that apply to the Project object are actually methods of the Application object and affect the active project.
2. The Object browser is your friend. It's in the MS Project VB Editor, under the View menu. A quick search of "calendar" will show you the relevant methods.

Here is a VBA example that you can adapt to your needs.

```
Sub AddCalendar()

    Application.BaseCalendarCreate "holiday", "Standard"
    Dim cal As Calendar
    Set cal = ThisProject.BaseCalendars("holiday")
    With cal
        .Period(#8/1/2014#, #9/1/2014#).Working = False
    End With

End Sub
```